# Have we over-hyped the evolution of LLM performance?

Tags: gpt, genai-ecosystem, users-psychology

Many brilliant theorists and visionaries, like the great Max Tegmark, have gone to extraordinary lengths to inform the public about the impending reality of AI surpassing human intelligence in the very near future.

But what if this viewpoint contains one critical flaw?

Generative Pre-trained Transformers (GPTs) are not human brains (obviously); they are data-driven computer programs, and as such their ability to predict sequential words will generally continue to increase as computing power and databases do. However, if we are on track for AI to outperform human consciousness, why, then, have we not patterned  their back-end infrastructure after our own thought process?

Humans are capable of almost simultaneously weighing multiple perspectives and scenarios in the creation of an idea. We cannot help but rationally "debate" with ourselves over the best plan of action; we question and criticize the validity of our very first ideas with opposing perspectives instantly, arriving at a more complex solution that is removed of some inherent cognitive bias.

LLMs currently have no inherent mechanism to combat this "cognitive bias." They return an answer like a glorified calculator, unable to "backtrack" and consider how their answer might have changed if they had considered an alternative path *in the first place*. Without such human-like mechanisms, how can we expect LLMs to, at least in the near future, to outpace human understanding and reasoning?

AI agents like the recently released Nvidia Eureka are already carrying on complex natural-language interactions and learning by trial and error; imagine the capabilities of such an agent equipped with an LLM that intelligently reconsidered every one of its actions before executing them.

Comment: These are the questions I ask myself - not having found a forum to discuss them with like-minded ones. GenAI SE obviously isn't such a forum, unfortunately. There seems to be a big divide between communities: enthusiasts and critics, and not so many inbetween (like I consider myself).

Comment: Another divide: between experts of GenAI and experts of the human brain. And inbetween experts of cognitive psychology.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Many NLP researchers are inbetween imho. They know that LLMs are surprisingly often SOTA  but they also see the many errors that LLMs still make.

Comment: Could you please add some quotes to expand on the first paragraph? It's unclear if they spoke about AI in the context of GPT and LLM, or if they had another idea.

Comment: @A.L Yes, I can add some of Tegmark's quotes to the first paragraph soon. He was also a signee of the "Pause Giant AI Experiments: An Open Letter" in March 2023, concerned mostly with "AI systems more powerful than GPT-4." [link](https://futureoflife.org/open-letter/pause-giant-ai-experiments/)

Answer (score 1):

> Have we over-hyped the evolution of LLM performance?

No, because we include I and I haven't, but there is a tendency to over-hyper AI progress, e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_winter. One can cast many AI tasks as language modeling tasks, but current SOTA LLM architectures (mostly, transformers) have their own limitations that will make it hard to outpace human understanding and reasoning on all AI tasks.